# How to deal with a monadic return value `m (Maybe Foo)`?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function which returns a value wrapped in a Monad,

```
produceMessage :: MonadIO m => KafkaProducer -> ProducerRecord -> m (Maybe KafkaError)
```

And  I have some code to call this function like so

```
err <- produceMessage prod message
return $ Right ()
```

The above code has been written by someone else, I am just trying to understand what is happening here. This is the rest of the function

```
messageSender :: KafkaProducer -> String -> Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ())
messageSender prod msg = do
  message <- mkMessage Nothing (Just $ pack msg)

  err <- produceMessage prod message
  --forM_ err print
  return $ Right ()
```

I have three specific questions,

1. I am confused what does the type signature of `produceMessage` mean? The type constraint is `MonadIO m`, what does this mean?
2. The return type is `m (Maybe KafkaError)`, so this returns a `Maybe` value wrapped in which monad?
3. How does `Right ()` come into picture here? In general I am really not 
   able to understand the last two lines of `messageSender`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type constraint means that the function can be used to return a value for any type `m` that has a `MonadIO` instance. Typically, that means `IO` itself or a monad stack built on top of `IO`.

The value returned by `produceMessage` is in part determined by the *caller*. Need an `IO (Maybe KafkaError)` value? You can get that, because `IO` has a `MonadIO` instance. Need a `MyCustomMonadStack (Maybe KafkaError)`? You can get that, if you define a `MonadIO` instance for `MyCustomMonadStack`.

Presumably, `Config.KafkaP` also has a `MonadIO` instance, based on how `messageSender` uses `produceMessage`.

`messageSender` has a return value of `Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ())`. The expression `return $ Right ()` first uses `Right ()` to produce a value of type `Either KafkaError ()`, then `return` is applied to *that* to produce a value of type `Config.KafkaP (Either KafkaError ())`. Note that the commented line `-- forM_ err print` is the only thing that might have used the value coming from `produceMessage`, so right now `messageSender` pretends that `produceMessage` worked, whether it did or not.

A more robust definition would actually use the return value of `produceMessage` in some way, perhaps like

```
err <- produceMessage prod message

return $ case err of
           Nothing -> Right ()
           Just theError -> Left theError
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation .